# Browser javascript require webworker

Tags: javascript, external, src, web-worker

I have one running webworker and I want it to be able to load external source. How can I do it
because it is run in another thread independent from DOM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importScripts method allows you to load external scripts that you can use in the web worker. Note: Scripts that need the window object won't work here, because the window object is only accessible on the UI Thread. More info can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dom-workerglobalscope-importscripts)

Answer (score 0):

Set up the external source so it supports [CORS](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dom-access-control-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing/).